# AVFoundation - How to set the Flash on Auto/Off before the image is captured

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation

i'm doing a Instagram-like app, i have ATM a working code that captures a photo and saves it in the photo library of the device. The camera preview works as the back/front camera switch. The problem i have now is to give a piece of code in the capture function to set the flash to .auto or .off if i hit a button, so when i snap a photo, the flash will work. Here my capture code :

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

        if let error = error {
            print("error occure : \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if  let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
            let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
            let dataImage =  AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer:  sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {
            print(UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size as Any)

            let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: dataImage as CFData)
            let cgImageRef: CGImage! = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
            let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil)
            self.cameracapture.image = image
        } else {
            print("some error here")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which I used:

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if device.hasTorch {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.On
            device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
            device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Auto
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Hope it help. :)

Comment: I've tried this code, it works, but the first line has a deprecated method, the new one for iOS 10 is: AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

Comment: About the rest of the code, device is an optional and xcode 8.2 tells me to put an ? after device.

Comment: Thanks by the way, the only thing that i need to understand is how i can tell the app to use the flash if it's set to auto before saving the actual image in the library. Tried in a dark enviroment, doesn't work :(

Comment: In a same enviroment, did normal camera flash work at auto mode?

Comment: It doesn't. When i press the button that i connected to the capture function, at .auto mode, the process only take the picture, it doesn't wait for the flash if needed

Answer (score 0):

```
func toggleFlash() {
    let avDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if (avDevice?.hasTorch)! {
        do {
            _ = try avDevice?.lockForConfiguration()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            report(err.localizedDescription)
        }

        if (avDevice?.isTorchActive)! {
            avDevice?.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.off
        } else {
            do {
                _ = try avDevice?.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0)
            } catch let err as NSError {
                report(err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        avDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
}
```

This is an example. You can also set the auto mode:

```
avDevice?.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.auto
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I implemented it and it works, but the code crashes my camerapreview. The image freezes, but the app doesn't crash until i hit the cameraswitch button. Can you help me solving this problem?

Comment: Update: ok the crash is solved(when in front camera mode, in back no problems). Now, when i press the button to take a picture, the app saves it but the flash, set to auto in a dark enviroment, doesn't work :(